# Realign columns with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm coding an article with three columns in Bootstrap. When I'm working with large screens it seems like

[image: Three columns large screen]

But when I'm working with small screens I want it to look like

[image: Small screen]

How can I make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to make use of the [Column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) with the `.col-xx-push-*` and `.col-xx-pull-*` classes.

One solution could look like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-2 col-sm-12">B</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-pull-6 col-sm-6">A</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">C</div>
</div>
```

Play with different breaking points by changing the `md` and `sm` to match your actual needs.

The above example in action: [jsbin.com/reqilege](http://jsbin.com/reqilege/2/)

Comment: oh its like i copied your answer, but cross ma finger's i didn't.

Comment: @rockStar I believe you.. cause that's the right solution but you were a bit late.. sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

You would need to `push` the `b div` into the 2nd middle and `pull` `A div` into the position of B div .
You can read more about column pushing and pulling [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="b" class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3 col-sm-12">Div B</div>
  <div id="a" class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-6 col-sm-6">Div A</div>
  <div id="c" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 ">Div C</div>
</div>
```

a Bootply sample [here](http://www.bootply.com/115702).

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to have the boxes in the order B,A,C. Then you offset B by A's width and by using absolute positioning you put A in the spot freed up.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <h1>B</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 shift-me">
            <h1>A</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <h1>C</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
    position: relative;
}
.row > div {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.shift-me {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .shift-me {
        position: static;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/valentin/MkbA2/

Comment: No need of introducing new classes for that. Check my answer, Bootstrap is providing you with classes that you can achieve a different order.

Comment: @Lipis you're right, your solution is much better and I upvoted it. I wasn't aware of column ordering